# How to communicate between Notification Extension and app for below use case?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

i have a specific use case:

client app is having movie data and also a feature to play movie in app.

Now i want to send notification to users, in notification payload i want to mention only movie id and movie poster url.
with notification service extension i can download movie poster url and then display it whenever notification appears on iphone screen.
plus notification also has custom button (play movie).

Now, i want to add feature like, whenever user tap on "play movie" button, notification extension should interact with my app and my app should start playing movie.

How can i communicate between app extension and app so that taping on custom action on extension , play movie on app ?

one possible way i can think of is, sharing handler classes on both targets. and then calling them.

is there any other better approach ?

Comment: do you want to go to app from click button in extension or play the video while still in notification

Comment: play the video in app.

Comment: you have a notification service and content  one ?

Comment: yes i have both.

Answer (score 0):

this was very easy then compared to what i thought.

so just posting an answer here, it can help other people.

You can handle selected actions from the delegate object of the shared UNUserNotificationCenter object.

**When the user selects an action, the system launches your app in the background** and calls the delegate’s userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) method.

Match the value in the actionIdentifier property of the response object to one of your app's actions.